# Getting wrong Url.PathAndQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have an action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Shopping cart", "Index", "Cart", new { returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, null)
```

and code that adds items to cart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addToCart_@(Model.ProductID)").click(function () {
            var quantity = $("#Quantity_@(Model.ProductID)").val();
            var productId = "@Model.ProductID";
            var dataToBeSent = { 'quantity': quantity, 'productId': productId};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Cart/AddToCart/',
                data: dataToBeSent,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#cartholder').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I'm trying to follow action link after adding item to cart, `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` has value `/Cart/AddToCart/`.

How can I get current url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you *are* setting your URL to `/Cart/AddToCart/`. It's right there in your AJAX request: `url: '/Cart/AddToCart/'`. That's it -- that's your URL (not counting the scheme and host).

You're specifying `type: "POST"`, so your payload (your `data: dataToBeSent`) isn't sent as part of the URL. The data only gets sent in the URL when you use GET. When you use POST, it's in the request body, not the URL.

(And don't just change it to a GET. It would seem to work for now, but would give you headaches later. GET requests can be cached by proxy servers -- not appropriate for requests that modify state, like adding things to a shopping cart.)

So in answer to the question you *asked,* `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` *is* how you get the URL. It's just that the URL is not what you *want.* You want to get your POST data, however that's normally done in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thanks. I'll investigate this moment. But I have just solved this task by geting current location by javascript and calling action method throug ajax. Now I have to redirect to result, returned by postback.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
 Request.RawUrl
```

This will get the URL you see in the browser. When using Url writing as with MVC the Request.Url will be the rewritten path.

Answer (score 1):

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url